# Repeating a capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a String containing zero or more numbers, then zero or more characters `ABCD`. I want to parse the number into one group, then all characters into a separate group per character. I've tried:

`([0-9]*)([ABCD])*`: Captures number correctly, but only the last letter

`([0-9]*)(([ABCD])*)`: Captures number correctly, but then first all the letters in one group, then only the last letter in a group

I understand why each of those results happen, but I don't know how to fix it. How do I change my regex to give me multiple groups for the matched characters? Bonus points if I don't get an empty group (`''` or `undefined`) if either the number or the letters aren't there.

For example:

`1A` => [1, A]

`99` => [99]

`CAB` => [C, A, B]

`1234ABCD` => [1234, A, B, C, D]

Comment: How does the regex know how long each of the groups is? Can we have test input strings and test output results?

Comment: Sure, I'll add some examples

Comment: Can you run two separate match functions?

Comment: I could, but I was hoping it could be done with a single regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have a built in method for "match all."  Since you know ahead of time that all of the letters will be the second match on, you can split these yourself:

```
var matches = "1234ABCD".match(/([0-9]*)([ABCD]*)/).slice(1);
matches = [matches[0]].concat(matches[1].split(""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to propose a new strategy: instead of trying to match the whole string at one attempt, match every number or character once with the [global modifier `/g`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) to return all matches.

**Regex**

```
/^\d+|[ABCD]/g
```

- `^\d+` matches an integer at the start of string
- `|` ...or...
- `[ABCD]` 1 of the four allowed characters.

**Code**

```js
subject = "1234ABCD";
pattern = /^\d+|[ABCD]/g;

matches = subject.match(pattern);


console.log(matches);
//=> ["1234", "A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put asterisk inside of group capture. Asterisk means 0 or more, so you trying to capture 0 or more signs from group capture, is this case your result is just first captured letter. But you need 0 or more of A B C D letters.

```
([0-9]*)([ABCD]*)
([0-9]*)([A-D]*) //same thing
```

//UPDATE

```
var match = "".match(/([0-9]*)([ABCD]*)/)
```

This code will return you array with three positions:

1. Mathed text
2. First matched group -> All numbers
3. Second matched group -> All letters

So to divide letters you can use

> match[2].split('');

Comment: This will put the letters in a capture group together, not each in its own group

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');

function reTest() {
  
  var re = /\b([0-9]*)([ABCD]*)\b/g;
  var str = test.value; 
  var found = "";

  str.replace(re, function(fullmatch, numbers, letters) {
    if (fullmatch == "") return;
    letters = letters.split("");
    found += "<span class='num'>" + numbers + "</span>"
    found += "<span class='letters'>" + letters + "</span>\n"
  });
  
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = found;
}

reTest();
```

```css
span.num {
  color:red;
}

span.letters {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="7" cols="40" id='test'>
123ABC
alpha
12345defg
bravo
CAB
19
9876vwxyz
...?
</textarea><br/>
<button onclick="reTest()">test</button><br/>
<pre id='result'></pre>
```